# What's a different way of inserting rows in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

I have a program where I reading lines from a text file into a datagridview, the file is an export from my budget program. I then want to insert a row after every week that totals the week. The only way I have found to do this is with DataGridView1.Rows.Count. The problem with this is, let's say the table has 3,000 rows and it's going to insert 1,000. Using the count method it would count a total of 3,000 rows after inserting 1,000 rows it will atop at the 2,000th row. Because 2,000 + 1,000 inserted = 3,000 count total. It seems the count method is looking at the index of the rows and every time a row is inserted the index is increased by one.

Here is a small sample program that I wrote to test the method out.

```
    Dim RowValue() As String = {"Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3", "Line 4", "Line 5", "Line 6", "Line 7", "Line 8", "Line 9", "Line 10"}
    For x = 0 To 9
        DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(x, RowValue(x))
    Next

    Dim y As Integer = 0
    Dim RowCount As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    For count = 1 To RowCount Step 2
        Dim InsertValue() As String = {"Insert 1", "Insert 2", "Insert 3", "Insert 4", "Insert 5", "Insert 6", "Insert 7", "Insert 8", "Insert 9", "Insert 10"}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(count)
        DataGridView1.Rows(count).Cells(1).Value = InsertValue(y)
        y += 1
    Next
```

As you can see I'm creating 10 rows at run time and trying to insert 10 rows but it only inserts 5. I have tried adding 1 to RowCount every time I insert a row but does not have any affect on the how it inserts the lines.

Is there another way to insert rows that would allow me to go until the end of the datagridview. Something like

```
Do Until (last row of datagridview)
    (do something here)
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was far too little information in your question to be able to answer it correctly, however here are some pointers.

The DataGridView is a VIEW object, and it should be used as such. There is no reason to ever have to add rows manually like you are doing. First get and organize your data, then bind it to the DGV, it is far more efficient, in particular when you have a lot of rows.

Also, adding a row in this case does not make a lot of sense. What you should do is use grouping and aggregates, however the DataGridView does not support grouping by default. There are extensions however, something like these for example http://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx .

If you do not want to do grouping, what you should do is add an extra column to your data source, and put in your totals in there.

Assuming this source file:

```
"RowId","RowAmount","WeekId"
1,1,1
2,2,1
3,3,1
4,4,2
5,5,2
6,6,2
7,7,3
8,8,3
9,9,3
```

This is what I would do (however keep in mind grouping is MUCH better, both visually and functionally...):

```
Private Sub LoadDataInDgv()
    Dim sourceFilename As String = "c:\source.txt"

    Dim dt As DataTable = ReadCsv(sourceFilename, ",", True, "WeekId ASC, RowId ASC")

    AddWeeklyTotals(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub AddWeeklyTotals(ByRef dt As DataTable)
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim row As Integer = 0
    Dim previousWeekId = CInt(dt.Rows(row)("WeekId"))

    dt.Columns.Add("WeeklyTotal", GetType(Double))

    Dim runningTotal As Double = 0

    For row = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim currentWeekId = CInt(dt.Rows(row)("WeekId"))
        Dim rowAmount = CDbl(dt.Rows(row)("RowAmount"))

        If currentWeekId <> previousWeekId Then
            dt.Rows(row - 1)("WeeklyTotal") = runningTotal
            runningTotal = rowAmount
            previousWeekId = currentWeekId
        Else
            runningTotal += rowAmount
        End If

        If row = dt.Rows.Count - 1 Then dt.Rows(row)("WeeklyTotal") = runningTotal

    Next
End Sub


Private Function ReadCsv(ByVal filename As String, ByVal delimiter As Char, ByVal hasHeaders As Boolean, ByVal orderByExp As String) As DataTable
    Dim result As New DataTable

    Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(filename)

    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""" & fi.DirectoryName & """;Extended Properties='text;HDR=" & If(hasHeaders, "Yes", "No") & ";FMT=Delimited(" & delimiter & ")';"
    Dim cmdStr As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & fi.Name & "]" & If(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderByExp), "", " ORDER BY " & orderByExp) & ";"

    Using Conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)
        Using Cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdStr, Conn)
            Using Adapter As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Cmd)
                Adapter.Fill(result)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return result
End Function
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: I don't really like to use extensions, but not adding in row and just adding the total to the Totals column will work. Thanks.